# Как задать поиск по базе данных Mysql?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Нужно как-то задать поиск базе Mysql. В базе имена, контакты и прочее, и все это выводить в `list view`.

Может у кото то есть чтото годное? Нужен поиск через `Edit Text`, `Seach view Bar` не вариант. Буду благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень общий вопрос. Тогда вот вам общий ответ:
На ваш `EditText` вешаете слушателя через `addTextChangedListener`. В методе `afterTextChanged` слушателя реализуете нужный вам поиск по текущему значению `EditText`. Логика поиска на ваше усмотрение. Это может быть как прямой запрос к базе данных, так и какая-нибудь сложная система с кэшированием.

Далее простой пример, но в таком виде использовать нельзя. Надо экранировать символы, чтобы злобный хакер не порушил вашу БД.

```
//Connection con = получение конекшена к базе данных.
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE your_field = '" + yourEditText.getText() + "'");
if (rs.next()) {
    // действия с результатом запроса.
}
rs.close();
```

Comment: Я нашел альтернативное решение .ненужно создавать поисковик я взял и навешал на него костюм ))))вышло чтото с чемто но в общем и целом работает гуд!